# How to add text along with carousel images in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I tried to add carousel along with text. But As far I can only add image carousel, Have no idea on how to add text. Please help me. Totally new.
I expect the output to be like image on above and text on below, but both need to swipe at same time.

I have no idea where to add the text field. I made this carousel with a example in youtube. But no example for carousel images with text. I tried something manually, But it all doesn't ended much well.
Please help me fix it. Thank-you

```
  class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Slider'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  PageController pageController;

  //Images List
  List<String> images = [
    '',
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    pageController = PageController(initialPage: 1, viewportFraction: 0.6);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: PageView.builder(
            controller: pageController,
            itemCount: images.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, position) {
              return imageSlider(position);
            }
        )
    );
  }

  imageSlider(int index) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: pageController,
        builder: (context, widget) {
          double value = 1;
          if(pageController.position.haveDimensions){
            value = pageController.page - index;
            value = (1 - (value.abs() * 0.3.clamp(0.0, 1.0)));
          }
          return Center(
            child: SizedBox(
              height: Curves.easeInOut.transform(value) * 400.0,
              width: Curves.easeInOut.transform(value) * 350.0,
              child: widget,
            ),
          );
        },
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: Image.asset(images[index],fit: BoxFit.cover),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You didn't add the image demonstrating what you want to achieve.

Comment: added. Please check

Answer (score 1):

Use column instead of container, so just replace this:

```dart
child: Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
    child: Image.asset(images[index],fit: BoxFit.cover),
),
```

with this:

```dart
child: Column(
    // To centralize the children.
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
        // First child
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: Image.asset(images[index],fit: BoxFit.cover),
        ),
        // Second child
        Text(
          'foo',
          style: TextStyle(
             // Add text's style here
          ),
        ),
    ]
),
```

OR instead of building your own carousal, you can use a ready to use one, e.g: [carousel_slider](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider) or [flutter_swiper](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_swiper)

Comment: but the code you give use static text right?, but i need different text for each image. Like one on the image that i attached above

Comment: Yes, I show you the idea. Then you can use a list for the texts just like the images. Or you can use list of maps so you have image's url and its text in the same map. Or you can create an item class for example which has two properties imageUrl and text then create List<Item>... So many solutions..

Comment: Have you got any workaround, I also need the image with text in carousal slider

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
child: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
      Text(
        heading,
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white,
          fontSize: 20.0,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        ),
      ),
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: Text(
          sub_heading,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 15.0,
          ),
          //textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

Comment: Please elaborate on where to place the code and how the code will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

***PageView with Next and Previous Functionality***

**Step 1:- Add PageView widget**

```
class _WalkThroughState extends State<WalkThrough> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  var height = 0.0;
  var width = 0.0;
  int mCurrentIndex = -1;
  List<Widget> pages=[PageOne(message: "Beauty Trends",),PageTwo(message: "Exclusive Offers",),PageThree(message: "Make your Kit",)];
  PageController _controller = new PageController();
  static const _kDuration = const Duration(milliseconds: 300);
  static const _kCurve = Curves.ease;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = PageController();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: height,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                    begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                    end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    colors: [startColorBackground, endColorBackground])),
          ),
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Flexible(
                child: Container(
                    child: PageIndicatorContainer(
                      key: _scaffoldKey,
                      child: PageView.builder(
                        controller: _controller,
                        onPageChanged: _onPageViewChange,
                        itemBuilder: (context, position) {
                          mCurrentIndex = position;
                          return pages[position];
                        },
                        itemCount: 3,
                      ),
                      align: IndicatorAlign.bottom,
                      length: 3,
                      indicatorSpace: 10.0,
                      indicatorColor: Colors.white,
                      indicatorSelectorColor: Colors.black,
                    )),
              ),
              Container(
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    // ignore: invalid_use_of_protected_member
                    mCurrentIndex != 0 ?Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0, bottom: 30.0),
                      child: GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            _controller.previousPage(
                                duration: _kDuration, curve: _kCurve);
                          },
                          child: Text('Prev', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),)),
                    ) : Container(),
                    mCurrentIndex != 2 ? Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 30.0, bottom: 30.0),
                      child: GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            _controller.nextPage(
                                duration: _kDuration, curve: _kCurve);
                          },
                          child: Text('Next', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),)),
                    ) : Container(),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );

  }
  _onPageViewChange(int page) {
    /*print("Current Page: " + page.toString());
    int previousPage = page;
    if(page != 0) previousPage--;
    else previousPage = 2;
    print("Previous page: $previousPage");*/
    setState(() {
      mCurrentIndex = page;
      print(mCurrentIndex);
    });
  }

}
```

**Step 2:- Add Pages with data**

Page 1

```
class PageOne extends StatelessWidget {
  final String message;
  var height = 0.0;
  var width = 0.0;

  PageOne({Key key, @required this.message}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Container(
      height: height - 50,
      child: Align(alignment: Alignment.center, child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: [
          Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0),
              child: Image(image: AssetImage("assets/images/banner_one.png"),)),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16.0),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                Text(message, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40, fontFamily: 'Playfair', fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                SizedBox(height: 30,),
                Text("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the \n printing and typesetting industry.", textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),),
    );
  }
}
```

Page 2

```
class PageTwo extends StatelessWidget {
  final String message;
  var height = 0.0;
  var width = 0.0;

  PageTwo({Key key, @required this.message}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            flex: 2,
            child: Container(
              width: width,
                child: Image(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  image: AssetImage("assets/images/banner_two.png"),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,)),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 40,
                  ),
                  Text(message, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40, fontFamily: 'Playfair', fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                  SizedBox(height: 30,),
                  Text("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the \n printing and typesetting industry.", textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Page 3

```
class PageThree extends StatelessWidget {
  final String message;
  var height = 0.0;
  var width = 0.0;

  PageThree({Key key, @required this.message}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return  Container(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            flex: 3,
            child: Container(
                width: width,
                child: Image(  width: double.infinity,
                  image: AssetImage("assets/images/banner_three.png"), fit: BoxFit.fill,)),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Container(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Text(message, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40, fontFamily: 'Playfair', fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                  SizedBox(height: 30,),
                  Text("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the \n printing and typesetting industry.", textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**You can add N number of pages. Right now am adding 3 pages with data**

**Colors.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const viewColor = Color(0xFFF5D9CE);
const textPinkColor = Color(0xFFF51678);
const buttonPinkColor = Color(0xFFF5147C);
const pinkColor = Color(0xFFF51479);
const pinkBackground = Color(0xFFF5C3C7);
const startColorBackground = Color(0xFFF5F4F2);
const endColorBackground = Color(0xFFF5EAE6);
```

[image: Page 1]

[image: Page 2]

[image: Page 3]

Answer (score 0):

This is complete working code with Image on top with text and dots. For this you need to use these two libraries:- " **carousel_slider: ^4.1.1 "**, **"smooth_page_indicator: ^1.0.0+2"**, update them to the latest.

```
   class MyItem {
    String itemName;
     String path;
  MyItem(this.itemName, this.path);
}

class craouselImage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _craouselImage createState() => _craouselImage();
}

class _craouselImage extends State<craouselImage> {
  int activeIndex = 0;
  List<MyItem> items = [
    MyItem("item 1", 'assets/images/appiconlogo.png'),
    MyItem("item 2", 'assets/images/Mockup4.png'),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          CarouselSlider.builder(
            itemCount: items.length,
            options: CarouselOptions(
              height: 400,
              viewportFraction: 1,
              autoPlay: true,
              enlargeCenterPage: true,
              enlargeStrategy: CenterPageEnlargeStrategy.height,
              autoPlayInterval: const Duration(seconds: 1),
              onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
                setState(() {
                  activeIndex = index;
                });
              },
            ),
            itemBuilder: (context, index, realIndex) {
              final imgList = items[index];
              return Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Expanded(child: buildImage(imgList.path, index)),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 15,
                  ),
                  buildText(imgList.itemName, index),
                ],
              );
            },
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 22,
          ),
          buildIndicator(),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 22,
          ),

          //buildText(itemName, index),
          // buildText(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildImage(String imgList, int index) => Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12),
        color: Colors.transparent,
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Image.asset(
            imgList,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
      );

  buildIndicator() => AnimatedSmoothIndicator(
        activeIndex: activeIndex,
        count: items.length,
        effect: const JumpingDotEffect(
            dotColor: Colors.black,
            dotHeight: 15,
            dotWidth: 15,
            activeDotColor: mRed),
      );

  buildText(String itemName, int index) => Align(
      alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
      child: Text(
        itemName,
        style: const TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, fontSize: 23, color: mRed),
      ));
}
```